# Can not Install My react native app in My phone but Getting response "Build Successfully"

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have react native app, when i am running App in local using "npx react-native run-android" it is working fine-good.
when i am making build of it then, getting messege "build Successfully" but when i installing apk in my android phone then it is doing crash, i can not open it...
how fix this error?

how i open it in my android phone?

how solve this error

there are some screenshots of it...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKr6E.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPr26.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/on1Ne.png)

Comment: analyze the error log and see, there might be several issues that might cause it. Something like package compatibility,

Comment: Run it with `Android Studio` and check logs in `logcat`, you have a native error. What is up with the notepad anyways?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.